# Generar doble encabezado de columnas en un datagridview de formulario (Windows form) en VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Buenas tardes, estoy armando un formulario donde se importa una tabla de SQl Server en un datagridview

Quiero armar doble encabezado como se muestra en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: el problema es de vista del control datagridview.. que probaste hasta ahora??? mira [ask] y [tour]

Comment: Es importante que indiques la tecnología que estas usando. Es asp.net? Winforms? Wpf?

Comment: Listo gbianchi, reformulé la pregunta como lo sugirió, me interesa que los usuarios comprendan mi pregunta.

Pikoh, estoy trabajando en Visual Basic con Windows forms

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Los encabezados se crean utilizando el método "Paint" del DataGridView, para su caso específico deberá generalizar con un ciclo la creación de los headers de agrupamiento

A continuación ilustro la forma de implementarlo:

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'DataSource
        Me.CMS_AttachmentTableAdapter.Fill(Me.KenticoEIBMDataSet.CMS_Attachment)
        AjustarPropiedadesGrid()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AjustarPropiedadesGrid()
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing
        'Alto de los headers, se coloca el doble del alto para poder adicionar los nuevos headers
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight * 2
        DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.BottomCenter
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Paint
        Dim formatoTexto As New StringFormat()
        formatoTexto.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        formatoTexto.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        Dim alto As Integer

        Dim encabezadoID As Rectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(0, -1, True)
        'Es el mismo para todos los encabezados
        alto = encabezadoID.Height / 2 - 2
        encabezadoID.X += 1
        encabezadoID.Y += 0
        encabezadoID.Width = encabezadoID.Width - 2
        encabezadoID.Height = alto
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.LightBlue), encabezadoID)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("", DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font, New SolidBrush(Color.Black), encabezadoID, formatoTexto)

        Dim encabezadoDatosBasicos As Rectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, -1, True)
        encabezadoDatosBasicos.Width = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, -1, True).Width + DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(2, -1, True).Width + DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(3, -1, True).Width + DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(4, -1, True).Width - 2
        encabezadoDatosBasicos.Height = alto
        encabezadoDatosBasicos.X += 1
        encabezadoDatosBasicos.Y += 0
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.LightSteelBlue), encabezadoDatosBasicos)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Datos Básicos", DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font, New SolidBrush(Color.Black), encabezadoDatosBasicos, formatoTexto)


        Dim encabezadoDimensiones As Rectangle = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(5, -1, True)
        encabezadoDimensiones.Width = DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(5, -1, True).Width + DataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(6, -1, True).Width - 2
        encabezadoDimensiones.Height = alto
        encabezadoDimensiones.X += 1
        encabezadoDimensiones.Y += 0
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.LightSlateGray), encabezadoDimensiones)
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Dimensiones", DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font, New SolidBrush(Color.Black), encabezadoDimensiones, formatoTexto)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnWidthChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewColumnEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnWidthChanged
        Dim rectanguloAreaControl As Rectangle = DataGridView1.DisplayRectangle
        rectanguloAreaControl.Height = DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight / 2
        Me.DataGridView1.Invalidate(rectanguloAreaControl)
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.Scroll
        Dim rectanguloAreaControl As Rectangle = DataGridView1.DisplayRectangle
        rectanguloAreaControl.Height = DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight / 2
        Me.DataGridView1.Invalidate(rectanguloAreaControl)
    End Sub
End Class
```

El resultado de mi ejemplo es el siguiente:

[image: DataGridView con Encabezados]
[image: DataGridView con Encabezados 2]

Comment: Me temo (aunque el OP no lo especifíca) que la pregunta se refiere a un `DataGridView` de winforms, no a Asp.NET, con lo que tu respuesta en ese caso no sería adecuada. Es importante antes de responder tener el máximo de información posible para que no sucedan cosas asi. Un saludo y bienvenido a [es.so]

Comment: Señor Eduardo, gracias por el código, me funcionó.